# k nearest neighbors with cross validation for accuracy score and confusion matrix

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning, scikit-learn, cross-validation

I have the following data where for each column, the rows with numbers are the input and the letter is the output.

```
A,A,A,B,B,B
-0.979090189,0.338819904,-0.253746508,0.213454999,-0.580601104,-0.441683968
-0.48395313,0.436456904,-1.427424032,-0.107093825,0.320813402,0.060866105
-1.098818173,-0.999161692,-1.371721698,-1.057324962,-1.161752652,-0.854872591
-1.53191442,-1.465454248,-1.350414216,-1.732518018,-1.674040715,-1.561568496
2.522796162,2.498153298,3.11756171,2.125738509,3.003929536,2.514411247
-0.060161596,-0.487513844,-1.083513761,-0.908023322,-1.047536921,-0.48276759
0.241962669,0.181365373,0.174042637,-0.048013217,-0.177434916,0.42738621
-0.603856395,-1.020531402,-1.091134021,-0.863008165,-0.683233589,-0.849059931
-0.626159165,-0.348144322,-0.518640038,-0.394482485,-0.249935646,-0.543947259
-1.407263942,-1.387660115,-1.612988118,-1.141282747,-0.944745366,-1.030944216
-0.682567673,-0.043613473,-0.105679403,0.135431139,0.059104888,-0.132060832
-1.10107164,-1.030047313,-1.239075022,-0.651818656,-1.043589073,-0.765992541
```

I am trying to perform KNN LOOCV to get accuracy score and confusion matrix.

```
from sklearn.neighbors import KNeighborsClassifier
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix
from sklearn.model_selection import LeaveOneOut
import pandas as pd

def main():
  csv = 'data.csv'
  df = pd.read_csv(csv)
  X = df.values.T
  y = df.columns.values
  clf = KNeighborsClassifier()
  loo = LeaveOneOut()
  for train_index, test_index in loo.split(X):
    X_train, X_test = X[train_index], X[test_index]
    y_train, y_test = y[train_index], y[test_index]
    clf.fit(X_train, y_train)
    y_true = y_test
    y_pred = clf.predict(X_test)
    ac = accuracy_score(y_true, y_pred)
    cm = confusion_matrix(y_true, y_pred)
    print ac
    print cm

if __name__ == '__main__':
  main()
```

However my results are all 0s. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: you may want to read [this](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/clustering.html#clustering-evaluation)

Comment: I think the first issue is that pandas mangles duplicates and the option to turn it off doesn't work... so `A A` becomes `A A.1`. I think the second issue is `y_true` and `y_pred` are supposed to be a list of all the values from the training, not a single value.

Comment: I am not sure why you are transposing your data so that it can match column labels. y should be the last column of your data and it should have labels A or B for each row along the column.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think your model does not get trained properly and because it only has to guess one value it doesn't get it right. May I suggest switching to KFold or StratifiedKFold. LOO has the disadvantage that for large samples it becomes extemely time consuming. Here is what happened when I implemented StratifiedKFold with 3 splits on your X data. I have randomly filled y with 0 and 1, instead of using A and B and have not trasposed the data so it has 12 rows:

```
from sklearn.neighbors import KNeighborsClassifier
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix
from sklearn.model_selection import StratifiedKFold
import pandas as pd

csv = 'C:\df_low_X.csv'
df = pd.read_csv(csv, header=None)
print(df)

X = df.iloc[:, :-1].values
y = df.iloc[:, -1].values

clf = KNeighborsClassifier()
kf = StratifiedKFold(n_splits = 3)

ac = []
cm = []

for train_index, test_index in kf.split(X,y):
    X_train, X_test = X[train_index], X[test_index]
    y_train, y_test = y[train_index], y[test_index]
    print(X_train, X_test)
    clf.fit(X_train, y_train)
    y_pred = clf.predict(X_test)
    ac.append(accuracy_score(y_test, y_pred))
    cm.append(confusion_matrix(y_test, y_pred))
print(ac)
print(cm)

# ac
[0.25, 0.75, 0.5]

# cm
[array([[1, 1],
       [2, 0]], dtype=int64), 

array([[1, 1],
       [0, 2]], dtype=int64),

 array([[0, 2],
       [0, 2]], dtype=int64)]
```

Comment: Can this be done with `LeaveOneOut`? I replaced the `StratifiedKFold` with `LeaveOneOut`, but it results in error.

Comment: Yes, it can but LOO will split the data into 11:1 twelve times. The syntax for the loop is a bit different. StratifiedKFold has y in the split(). Could you check the way you are preparing your data. It will be good to have a df with the data from X and the column with the labels A/B last. So, if you have six column with independent data, the seventh column should have the labels as the dependent variable. You can then split them the way it is done in the example above.